# Unity - avoid gimbal lock when using euler angles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, euler-angles

I wish to rotate a certain object to a given position using `eulerAngles`. It works nice and neat, except that sometimes it gives me a *gimbal lock*, meaning it rotates around in the wrong direction. I tried using `Quaternions` but to no avail, even though they rid me of the gimbal lock, they just don't do what they should. The goal is to rotate to a given rotation.
The code how I want to do the magic:

```
    IEnumerator RotateTo_Euler(Transform whatToRotate,Vector3 toThis,float inTime)
{
    Vector3 idle = whatToRotate.eulerAngles;
    for (float t = 0.0f; canRotate && t < 1.0f; t += Time.deltaTime / inTime)
    {
        whatToRotate.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(idle, toThis, t);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

note that the `z` value, that is changing in my case, will never be negative so I have no clue what causes the gimbal lock.

Comment: Quaternions are the way to go. What do you mean by "they just don't do what they should"?

Comment: I didn't want to mix the two topics (avoid gimbal lock and how to quaternion) hence I didn't write it here. 
When using Quats, at first they rotate to the desired position, but next time they don't. I give them exact values, not something like `currentRotation.z - 0.1f`. I really have no clue what to do there.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not calling this function from multiple places? Can you put Debug.Log before the for loop and see how many times it gets called.

Comment: Nope, it's called only when I want it to, not one more.

Comment: By the way, I tried your idea with the Debug.Log and thus I know it is called when it is needed :D my prior comment looked like I just know it without testing.

Comment: I don't think this is a gimbal lock issue. Do you have an animated image for this? I want to see what's going on. Also, where and is RotateTo_Euler called from?

Comment: It is called using a `StartCoroutine()` and _not_ in a loop or something that can be repeated within an amout of time.
No animation, sorry, the problem is that I need to rotate it to a direction that's `z` is say 20 degrees less than my current. It doesn't chose the shortest and obvious direction but goes around.

Comment: Heh I might have solved it. I used `Quaternions` but I gave the input like `Quaternion.Euler(myDesiredEulerAngle)`. I hope I don't say anything too early, but messing around with it and it still works fine. 
@Programmer thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Ok. Let us know if the problem returns.

Comment: Interesting you tried Lerp in a coroutine with a for loop; does 'idle' get set every frame, or many times a frame?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. AFAIK the thread returns to the for loop that is after I "save" the idle position. 
And luckily no, the problem never returned. Thanks for the help, all of you.

Answer (score 1):

Quaternions are the way to go. They are "proper" rotations and allow you to do everything in a sense of rotation. It is worth spending some hours with the basic concepts and useful calculations of quaternions.

I suggest you write viable conversions euler > quaternion, quaternion > euler and then do the rotation as quaternions.

(There is Quaternion.Lerp what should work similar to your code example)